# How to select type base on string in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I have function `select` to fetch data from database.

There is only one parameter `entityType` (for example `A`, `B`).

For `A` I will return always `ResponseA`, for `B` I will return always `ResponseB`.

Is there any way hwow to chose `Response` type base on `entityType`?

My code is:

```
type ResponseA = {
    responseAProperty: string;
}

type ResponseB = {
    responseBProperty: number;
} 

function select(entityType: "A"|"B"): ResponseA | ResponseB {
    console.log(entityType);
    return {} as any; // database fetch 
}
```

I tried to use google and SO search. I made a simple demo code with simple logic.

EDIT:
**Final code after community help is:**

```
type ResponseA = {
    responseAProperty: string;
};

type ResponseB = {
    responseBProperty: number;
};

type ResponseC = {
    responseCProperty: number;
};

type ResponseD = {
    responseDProperty: number;
};

type SelectEntityToResponse = {
    A: ResponseA;
    B: ResponseB;
    C: ResponseC;
    D: ResponseD;
};

class Querier<T> {

    select<EntityType extends (keyof T)>(entityType: EntityType): T[EntityType]{
        console.log(entityType);
        return {} as any; // database fetch
    }

}

const a = new Querier<SelectEntityToResponse>().select("A");
//    ^?
const b = new Querier<SelectEntityToResponse>().select("B");
//    ^?
const c = new Querier<SelectEntityToResponse>().select("C");
//    ^?
const d = new Querier<SelectEntityToResponse>().select("D");
//    ^?
```

Comment: I am confident that this is a duplicate question. See [overloaded function signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) in the TypeScript handbook.

Comment: And/or [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html): https://tsplay.dev/WoAygN

Comment: @T.J.Crowder how can I do it for 10 types?

Comment: @jsejcksn Is there any way how can I do it without typing overload code? I would like to create library without allow user edit code. They can write only type.

Comment: @xohek16117 - You *can* just chain the conditionals: https://tsplay.dev/mq3arw But at that point, I'd probably have a lookup type instead: https://tsplay.dev/NB5pxw (the lookup type is `SelectEntityToResponse` in that example). Obv both of those examples only have four branches, but you get the idea...

Comment: @xohek16117 It sounds like you might want to modify/expand the possibilities in the future: if that's the case and it were my code, I'd use a map like [T.J.Crowder mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74343428/how-to-select-type-base-on-string-in-typescript?noredirect=1#comment131247458_74343428).

Comment: Thank you. My final result is: https://tsplay.dev/mbQO9N